# updating the data records automatically in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I currently have `User` model that has the `name` attribute and am using ajax to grab selected data.

JS looks like this:

```
$("#save").click(function(){
  var checkedUser = [];
  $.each($("input[name='selected_user']:checked"), function(){
    checkedUser.push($(this).val());
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/users/<%= current_user.id %>/friend", 
    data: {checked_user: checkedUser}, 
  })
```

controller action:

```
def friend
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  checked_user = params[:checked_user]
  @user = User.where(id: checked_user)
end
```

I want to build a function that updates the data records based on checkbox input and want to give time range.

For example, if there is a user and has a friends list and the user checks friend 'A' and submit, the friend A should not show on the user's friends list as checked as block for set time (could be 24hrs or 10hours) and once time's up, I want them back to the list again so it is like:

user -> set friend A as not to show for 10mins -> showing friend A as checked on the friend list -> after 10mins -> the friend A is showing again.

Q1) Should I make a new attribute that has boolean type then do update the attribute? or is there any better way to do this?

Q2) How to handle the times like if I wanted to uncheck the checked user after 10mins, should I use JS?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question of yours is most likely to be closed as 'too broad' again. SO is not the place where you say, "I have this requirement and I want help getting started". It's more like "I have this requirement, this db architecture, these models, controllers, etc.. I expect them to behave like this but they behave like something else".

Comment: alright I may update my contents then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I would add two attributes, `duration` and `checked_at`, or maybe just one like `expires_at`. This will make #2 easier.

2) You will want to use a worker to schedule a periodic [background job](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs), using it to delete any entries that have expired.

Comment: thanks for your help but I dont get get the second answer what do you mean by use a worker, you mean using gem?

Comment: Yeah, basically, some background process that runs periodically. You can make jobs do whatever you want. In this case, it could just check every minute for expired entries.