# Updating a boolean attribute automatically after a certain of time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Similar Question I have posted**:
[Updating attribute automatically in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959051/updating-attribute-automatically-in-rails)

I am very new to Rails and JS. I recently started building a web application and faced some difficulties. I have posted some questions related but did not get a solution what I wanted.

**My scenario:**

What I am trying to do is, when user A checked user B as mute, the user B is disappear on user A's friends' list for a certain time (10mins or 20mins).

**Data Structure:**

I have `User` model that has a `boolean attribute` named `mute`. The `mute` is set `false` as a default value and the `mute` is updated to `true` when the user is selected from the list.

**Main Question:**

> I sort of made something I was planning to build but I have no idea
>   how to update the `mute` to `false` again **after a certain of time**. Is
>   there anyway to complete that? I searched some infomration and some
>   people said use **whenever gem** but I don't think that is not like what I wanted. I will very appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: You really need a background job to schedule for this, so that it kicks in after an specified amount of time. `whenever` works through a cronjob, so it is a good choice or you can use any schedular job for this.  You can't rely on client side for this.

Comment: Thanks for answering and please understand me if this is a silly question if I use `whenever` or other scheduler jobs, is that possible to make it like this => once the `mute` attribute is set to `true` the scheduler jobs started counting the certain time such as 20mins and after 20mins, it updates `mute` to false again. Sorry again, I am quite new and someone told me `whenever` is not really good for this task so I am a bit confused now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [updating the data records automatically in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941969/updating-the-data-records-automatically-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a background process which can be triggered after a configured time when updating the `mute` field to `true`. In this process you can update the field back to `false`.

Some examples are **Delayed Job**, **Backburner**, **Redis** etc.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

https://github.com/nesquena/backburner

Comment: [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/e29ecaca024e0791053ced5c02599f71) for the `delayed_job_active_record` (`delayed_job`) gem. However, this is not perfect, since every update for user after setting *mute* to `true` adds a delayed job. You might need to add a field that marks if an delayed job (timer) is running or not.

Comment: I got an error like **undefined method `after_save' for UsersController:Class Did you mean? after_action**, should I just change it to action

Comment: I think you are invoking from a controller. You should be doing it inside your User model.

Comment: Ahh right, sorry about being silly. I put it in the User model and according to @JohanWentholt, I can see `User.delay(run_at: 10.minutes.from_now).update(id, mute: false)`. how can I find specific users that have been marked as mute? like `User B` and `User C` could be marked at different time and the `mute` should be updated at different time. Sorry to bother you guys...

Comment: @js_beginner `muted_users = User.where(mute: true)` should return all muted users. You could also add a `:muted` scope if you are going to call it often. `scope :muted, -> { where(mute: true) }` in your `User` model lets you call `User.muted` instead.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Thanks for ur helps, Is that possible to update `mute` at different times depending on updated time because like I mentioned It is possible `User B` and `User C` could be updated at different time. For example, `User B` is updated at 11pm and `User C` is updated at 11:10 so `User B` needs to be unmuted at 11:10 and `User C` needs to be unmuted at 11:20... Not sure if I explained well...

Comment: @js_beginner This can be done on the server by updating a class instance variable when a user is being muted or unmuted. However this is most likely not what you're searching, since the change must also be present on the clients I guess. This means that the clients should poll for changes using AJAX, or push the changes from the server to the clients using [ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) (cleaner solution). This can't be further explained in the comments, and should be dedicated to a new question if you have any problems with it.

Comment: @JohanWentholt I am currently using ajax to update mute/unmute users. Can you tell me little more about that? Or should I post a new question

Comment: I have posted a new question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959051/updating-attribute-automatically-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more column which stores the times `muted_at` , when user A mute User B, Mute value becomes false and muted_at will be DateTime.current. In the scheduler job, you can check after every 5 seconds whether it is mute time is greater then 30 minutes or not . if its exceedd 20 mintues then change value to false.

You can use [gem sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for back ground job and [gem sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) for schedule jobs

In your case, you can create one worker class which check after every 5 seconds whether you need to change value of mute or not

```
:schedule:
  hello_world:
    cron: '0 * * * * *'   # Runs once per minute
    class: HelloWorld
```

HelloWorld will be your job, which run after every 1 minute and check whether the mute time exceed then current time

condition will be like below

```
User.last.update_column(mute:, false) if muted_at + 20.minutes < DateTime.current
```

So in this way you can solve your issue. let me know if you need more information

Comment: Very appreciate ur help I will leave some comments after giving a shot!

Comment: Okay sure, i can only give you idea. code and other things, you have to manage through your self. so you can learn better

Comment: So quick question, is that possible if `User A` `mute` set `true` at **10:00am** and `User B`'s `mute` set `true` **at10:10am** but is that possible to make `User A`'s `mute` to `false` at **10:10am** and `User B`'s `mute` to false at **10:20** since the `mute`time is **10min**

Comment: Yes. you just have to check it in background job

Comment: First of fetch all users which have mute true, check if mute is greater then 20 minutes of current time then set it to false

Answer (score -3):

You may use the following piece of code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
// code
}, 1000);
```

where as 1000 in milliseconds

Comment: This is not correct way to do this. What if, I closed the browser?

Comment: Good to know, Let me see!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Sure buddy! will do it!

Comment: In JavaScript? For a rails question?